# javascript unload event in safari mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, safari

I'm working on a webapp for iPad with jQtouch and jQuery. The webapp is used in a store and viewed through AVD browse which send me email alerts when the device is shook or disconnected from power. However, I also want to know when the webapp has been closed. I tried to use $(window).bind('unload', function(){}); but it doesn't work neither in Safari Mobile nor AVD browse. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 6):

I have an answer. It's not what we were hoping for.

The technical definition of unload from http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html is:

> The unload event occurs when the DOM
>   implementation removes a document from
>   a window or frame. This event is valid
>   for BODY and FRAMESET elements.

I also got a reply from some in the know at Apple: "Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find an event that fires when the Home button is clicked!  I think the most appropriate event for this might be the pagehide event.  This event actually does fire in Safari on iOS when you switch to the "tabs" view to open a new page, but not when you click the home screen icon :-("

Comment: thanks a lot for your investigation. Your answer will help me in soon I think.